# VBA Trouble Shooting for Selecting ranges on correct sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write some VBA code to identify the correct rows based on an if statement, and then copy specific values from each row to a different sheet to make a more concise table. I have made several vba programs before and can normally fix the bugs on my own, but I cannot figure out this error. Every time I run this it throws a 400 error and its always when its trying to access the if statement right after the start of the for loop. All of the code within the for loop does not work correctly. I have used almost this exact code in a different program and it works there. I believe it has something to do with trying to reference sheets it doesn't think it has the privilege to access, but all the sheets are unprotected and not hidden.

If anyone has a better way to do this or can explain to me my error I would really appreciate it. I feel like there is a big picture idea I'm not fully understanding. I just don't know what it is in this case and googling/looking through multiple threads on this site didn't help.

---

```
'Variables for the subs
Dim RowStart As Integer  
Dim RowEnd As Integer  
Dim ColYel As String  
Dim ColRed As String  

Dim ProdName As String  
Dim ActUse As String  
Dim UseDif As String  
Dim ActCost As String  
Dim CostDif As String  

'Set a place to temporarily paste values and copy as a table'  
'TAKEN CARE OF BY SHEET TABLE'  
Dim count As Integer
```

---

```
Public Sub Yellow()
'Unprotect sheet
'ThisWorkbook.Unprotector

'reset table formatting
Sheets("Table").Range("A1:E36").Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).Weight = xlThin

'Turn off updating and make table visible
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Find Yellow rows by identifying ColYel = 1
RowStart = 8
RowEnd = 34
ColYel = U
ColRed = V

ProdName = A
ActUse = G
UseDif = i
ActCost = K
CostDif = M

'Set count to 2 for table sheet
count = 2

'Copy product name, actual use, use dif, actual cost, cost dif
MsgBox "Starting Loop"
For i = RowStart To RowEnd
    If ActiveSheet.Range(ColYel & i).Value = 1 Then
        ActiveSheet.Range(ProdName & i).Copy (Sheets("Table").Range("A" & count))
        ActiveSheet.Range(ActUse & i).Copy (Sheets("Table").Range("B" & count))
        ActiveSheet.Range(UseDif & i).Copy (Sheets("Table").Range("C" & count))
        ActiveSheet.Range(ActCost & i).Copy (Sheets("Table").Range("D" & count))
        ActiveSheet.Range(CostDif & i).Copy (Sheets("Table").Range("E" & count))
        count = count + 1
    End If
Next i
MsgBox "Finished Loop"

'Copy new table to clipboard.
Sheets("Table").Range("A1:E" & count).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlThick
Sheets("Table").Range("A1:E" & count).Copy

'Turn on updating and make table visible = falst
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

'Reprotect sheet
'ThisWorkbook.Protector

End Sub
```

Comment: Replace `ActiveSheet` with the specific sheet you want to be on  ... `Sheets("mySheet")` for example.

Comment: I tried doing that. It still threw the same error.

Comment: What are `U`, `V`, `A`, `etc`. ... are these meant to be variables that are defined elsewhere? Or do you want the *actual literal string*? If so, surround them in `""` and it will work.

Comment: Oh my goodness.. That is exactly the error. Haha thank you! It was much more obvious than I thought. Thank you so much Scott!

Comment: Sorry I just saw the comment by @ScottHoltzman

Comment: Still thank you Lowpar. Silly mistake that I just didn't realize, so I'm glad you and Scott did. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Sub Yellow()
'Unprotect sheet
'ThisWorkbook.Unprotector

'reset table formatting
'Sheets("Table").Range("A1:E36").Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).Weight = xlThin

'Turn off updating and make table visible
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Find Yellow rows by identifying ColYel = 1
RowStart = 8
RowEnd = 34
ColYel = "U"
ColRed = "V"

ProdName = "A"
ActUse = "G"
UseDif = "i"
ActCost = "K"
CostDif = "M"

'Set count to 2 for table sheet
Count = 2

'Copy product name, actual use, use dif, actual cost, cost dif
MsgBox "Starting Loop"
For i = RowStart To RowEnd
    If ActiveSheet.Range(ColYel & i) = 1 Then
        ActiveSheet.Range(ProdName & i).Copy (Sheets("Table").Range("A" & Count))
        ActiveSheet.Range(ActUse & i).Copy (Sheets("Table").Range("B" & Count))
        ActiveSheet.Range(UseDif & i).Copy (Sheets("Table").Range("C" & Count))
        ActiveSheet.Range(ActCost & i).Copy (Sheets("Table").Range("D" & Count))
        ActiveSheet.Range(CostDif & i).Copy (Sheets("Table").Range("E" & Count))
        Count = Count + 1
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

You never put the strings in inverted commas, i.e., ColRed = "V" not ColRed = V